# Silverstripe: Import Widget-specific CSS on Widget install

Tags: php, css, sass, silverstripe

I was wondering if there was a way to import a SASS file to my CSS directory AFTER the widget has been installed, and remove it, if the widget is removed?

Comment: It's really hard to understand what the question is. Can you explain in more detail? Maybe also mention the version of SilverStripe you're using?

Comment: @bummzack Sorry. What I meant is...

I have a widget. I have a SASS file in the widget's directory folder. When I run composer update to import the widget in to my silverstripe installation, I'd like the SASS file to get moved in to the 'mysite' directory.

I'm on 3.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want via composer [script hooks](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md). These can only be applied to your root composer file though.